@vars and @symfuns suddenly not defined in Julia while using SymPy
I recently updated Julia from 1.9.0 to 1.10.3 and all my codes that used @vars or @symfuns now don´t work because they say that they aren´t defined even though I´m using SymPy. Before the update it all worked without any problem.
Here´s an example code:
using SymPy
@vars x

And here is the output
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: `@vars` not defined

Is there any way to fix it? Or any alternatives I can use to those functions?

I think they might've both been deprecated and rolled under @syms

Refer to SymPy.jl commits d7610a5 and df4067e. Both @vars and @symfuns were deprecated in the former and removed in the latter:

The macro @vars is deprecated in favor of @syms; @symfuns is deprecated, as @syms can be used.

